# A problem about periodic functions

Tags: analysis, functions, periodic-functions

Suppose that $f(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a periodic function with a minimal positive period $T$. Can $g(x)=f(x^2)$ be periodic?

I know it is impossible if the condition $\forall x \in (0,T),f(x)\not=f(0)$ is added. But Is there a counterexample for the general case? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I wonder if the condition $\forall x \in (0,T), f(x) \neq f(0) $ is added to take care of "witty" counterexamples as $f(x) = 0$ everywhere

Comment: @An aedonist In that case, $f$ doesn't have a minimal positive period.

Comment: I see, a period of $0$ would not count, thanks

Comment: @Darkrim What about $\sin x?$

Comment: @mfl Neither $\sin x^2$ nor $|\sin x^2|$ are periodic.

Comment: @M.Winter Sorry, I have misread the question. Thank you.

Comment: I believe the answer to be no, and I think there might be a "geometrical" argument. If $f(x)$ has fundamental period $p$, we can see it as a map $S^1(p):=\mathbb{R}/p\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$. If $f(x^2)$ has fundamental period $q$, then it would be a map $S^1(q)\to\mathbb{R}$. But the map $x\mapsto x^2$ doesn't give a well defined map $S^1(p)\to S^1(q)$ and this should imply some kind of contradiction. I couldn't make this argument formal yet.

Comment: Assume that f is continuous, then the answer is no.

Comment: Assume that f is continuous, then the answer is no.However, if f is not continuous,maybe you can consider $ f(x)=1_{\{x ~is ~an ~  algebraic~ number\}}(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

This question is well above my league, I will nevertheless attempt a solution for learning purposes, apologising to anybody's whose time I waste in the process.

$f$ is a periodic function, with minimal period $T$.
Without loss of generality, we can rescale the $x$-axis so to have period $T=1$. Let us still call the re-scaled function $f$.

By definition, $$f(0) = f(1) = \cdots =  f(j)$$ for any $j \in \mathbb{N}$.

As $g(x) = f(x^2)$, this implies
$$g(0) = g(1) = g(\sqrt{2}) = \cdots = g(\sqrt{j}) $$ for any $j \in \mathbb{N}$.

If $g$ were periodic of period $T'$, the number of occurences on which  $g$ attained the value $g(0)$ between  any $x$ and $x+ T'$ would be constant.
If the number of such occurrances were finite, we would reach a contraddiction.

Indeed it would not be possible  as there is an increasing number of values of the type $\sqrt{j}$, $j \in \mathbb{N}$, in intervals $(x, x+ T')$ as $x$ increases.

The case whereby the function $g$ attains the value $g(0)$ infinitely often over a period is being considered, following the observations made in the comments by M. Winter.

Comment: You are right, that there must be the same "amount" of $g(0)$ in every interval $[x,x+T']$ and that the density of $\sqrt j$ is increasing. *But* your argument would only work if $g$ attains the value $g(0)$ *only* at $\sqrt j$ and nowhere else. But we do not know this.

Comment: @M. Winter, I thought about that, and did not worry me too much. Indeed we do not know that $g$ attains the value $g(0)$ only at $\sqrt{j}$ and nowhere else. But we know it will attain the value $g(0)$ exactly $k$ times in any interval $[x, x + T']$, certainly on $\sqrt{j}$ and possibly somewhere else. By having $x$ increasing, we show that it has to attain the value $g(0)$ more than $k$ times, even by counting only the points such as $\sqrt{j}$.

Comment: It could attain the value $g(0)$ infinitely often.

Comment: I see, I gave for granted that would infringe the "minimal period" condition (which I interpreted as , the period of $f$ is bounded above away from zero. Will work on it.

Comment: Your arguments so far shows that there can be no such function $f$ which is continuous on any open interval. If $f$ is continuous, so is $g$. But because the set $g^{-1}(0)$ is dense, we have $g=0$, hence $f=0$.

Comment: @M.Winter Apologies for bumping an old comment but how do we know that $g^{-1}(0)$ is dense?

Comment: @Jam If I recall correctly, then because the set $\sqrt j\pmod{T'}$ is dense in $[0,T']$ and $g^{-1}(0)$ contains this set.

Comment: @M.Winter Yes, I see it now. Thanks a bunch. Though I'm not sure we can conclude that $g$ is identically zero.

Comment: @Jam If $g$ would be continuous and identically zero on a dense set, then it would be zero everywhere. This is how we conclude that it cannot be continuous. You can find more on this question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/282756).

Comment: @M.Winter Ah, ofc, sorry. I didn't realise that was using the assumption of continuity.